# Unconventional usage of "way"

Tags: grammar

> So, if you are thinking of a particular context, you should specify it. In its current form, the question is *way* too broad, and *way* too general-reference.

Since, after having consulted some dictionaries, I'm not able to find a definition that fits, can anyone explain how "way" is used in that passage?

Answer (score 5):

This ***[way](https://www.google.com/search?q=way%20meaning)*** is an adverb, not a noun.

This use of "way" as an adverb is common in spoken English, to emphasize the quality it intensifies, meaning: far, very, really, or extremely.

For example, you can think of the phrase ***way too broad*** in your example as "far too broad" or "really too broad". It's the same for the *way* in ***way too general-reference***.

<sub>Also note that "general reference" is a noun, but in the example sentence, it's used as if it's an adjective.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

As @Damkerng said, the word "way" is functioning as an adverb in your sentence, and it simply means "much", as in:

> ... the question is *much* too broad, and *much* too general-reference.

I'll add that "way" can be repeated in spoken (or informal written) English for emphasis:

> ... the question is *way, way* too broad ...

This clause would mean that the question is *even more broad* than a question that is already *way too broad*. When spoken, the second "way" is often emphasized and spoken more slowly than the first "way".